# How to change badge count?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit, cksubscription

I’m using CKSubscription to send push notifications, I send them well and the device receives everything correctly, but my badge count is always +1 to what it was before? How can I set it to 0 after the app was run?

I have added this code to func application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

But when you run the app, the badge disappears, receiving the next push notification the number rises again.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with CKModifyBadgeOperation putting it in applicationDidBecomeActive

```
let badgeOp = CKModifyBadgeOperation(badgeValue: 0)
badgeOp.modifyBadgeCompletionBlock = { (error) -> Void in 
if error != nil { print (“error with the badge”)
} 
else {
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 }
}
CKContainer.default().add(badgeOp)
}
```

all works!!!! So happy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just not zeroing it out at the right place?

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not called when your app resumes from background, only when it is actually launched. The most common use of the badge I can think of is when you are receiving notifications and you want to zero them when the user has seen the notifications. So that's where you have to set your `applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`

If for instance your app is just a single view with a list of messages and just seeing that list is enough to tell you the user has read the message you could use `applicationWillEnterForeground` instead. That is called every time you come back from being in the background.

You still also have to zero it out when a notification comes in while the app is in the foreground though.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! Actually I have tried it, I even tried to put this piece of code in func application (... didReceiveRemoteNotification...) I thought that the problem might be that I don’t update badge count in CloudKit dashboard in my subscription type, thus it increases, but I have no idea how to do that...